# How do I disable the click event in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, removechild

I have implemented Fileupload drag and drop in jQuery PHP using ajax posting.

I'm using **html input file** tag with id `upload_btn` and a div with id `total` for drag and drop the files.

In order to remove the browse button on the screen and to use the div (`total`) as browse file. I have added these two lines on the top of the `$(document).ready(function() {`:

```
  document.getElementById('total').addEventListener('click',function(){
  document.getElementById('fileToUpload').click();
```

After dropping the selected files in div(`total`) listing all the file here. If any of the selected file exceeds the max file size, I'm displaying delete button for each file to remove the file from list. But after click on delete, selected file is removing success but as I have written the above mentioned two statements again the browse event is calling. How can I disable browse here in this situation?

Displaying all the files in div tag with id `total` as follows:

```
 $(upfiles).each(function(index, file) 
                    {
                        if(total_size > limit) // size limit comparision
                             display_removebutton = "<img width='20px' style='cursor:pointer;' height='20px' class='class_remove' id='remove_"+int_loop+"' src='images/DeleteRed.png' />"
                        size = Math.round( file.size / 1024 );
                        if(size > 1024) 
                                size_display =  Math.round(size / 1024 * 100)/100 + ' mb'; // converted to mb
                        else
                                size_display = size + ' kb';
                        if(size > limit)
                        {
                            style_limitexceed = "style='background:#FFCCCC;border-radius:17px;height:30px;margin-top:6px;'";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            style_limitexceed = "";
                        }
                        $('#total').append("<div id='div_selec"+int_loop+"' "+style_limitexceed+"><b>File Name :</b> "+file.name + "<b> Size:</b>" + size_display + display_removebutton + "</div>"+"" ); 
                        $("#remove_"+int_loop).click(function() {
                        if(confirm( "Do you want to delete file : "+ file.name+ "?" ) === true)
                        {

// here we need to remove the click event for **fileupload input tag**
                                var curr_id = this.id;
                                var id = curr_id.substr(7);
                                $("#div_selec"+id).empty();
                                upfiles.splice(index, 1)
                                $("#div_selec"+id).fadeOut('slow');
                                total_size = total_size - (file.size/1024);
                                if(total_size < limit)
                                {
                                    $("#total img:last-child").remove()
                                    $("#div_errorLog").fadeOut('slow');
                                }
                        }
                         });
                         int_loop++;
                    });
```

Hope you understand what my problem is.. waiting for your suggestions...!

**edit :**

What exactly need is, when total div has some content then browse event should not file, when clicking on remove `display_removebutton` or even `total` div.

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/6W2LB/) : stopPropagation();

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/6W2LB/1/)** : preventDefault();

---

You can stop the click event by

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Or

```
event.preventDefault();
```

The `event.stopPropagation()` method stops the bubbling of an event to parent elements, preventing any parent event handlers from being executed.

---

In your code.

```
document.getElementById('total').addEventListener('click',function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('fileToUpload').click();

});
```

Comment: This will have the same effect if you use preventDefault?

Answer (score 0):

[JQUERY DOC](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/)

In addition to keeping any additional handlers on an element from being executed, this method also stops the bubbling by implicitly calling `event.stopPropagation().` To simply prevent the event from bubbling to ancestor elements but allow other event handlers to execute on the same element, we can use `event.stopPropagation()` instead.

Use event.isImmediatePropagationStopped() to know whether this method was ever called (on that event object).

use the `event.stopImmediatePropagation();` or `event.stopPropagation()`to stop the click event.

```
$('document').ready(function(){
       document.getElementById('total').addEventListener('click',function(event){
      document.getElementById('fileToUpload').click();
      event.stopImmediatePropagation(); (or) event.stopPropagation()
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("yourClass").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: can you please give little explanation. where exactly i have to use your code

Comment: can you please give the final dom structure that is generated ?

Are you saying that when you click the "delete button" the "total" click is fired ???

Comment: nope. the process is when i click on div total for the first time **fileToUpload** click event should happen. and after dragging the files into the **total** div then if the file size increases the max size limit then **display_removebutton** button will appear and now when i click on **display_removebutton** , **fileToUpload** event should not happen

Comment: This means that the "display_removebutton" div is inside the "total" div . Am i right ???

Comment: yes so this is the problem . to resolve this do these things :

when "total" div is clicked add a class to the "total" div and name that class as "active".
and change code to - 

document.getElementById('total').addEventListener('click',function(){
if(!$(this).hasClass("active"))
{
  document.getElementById('fileToUpload').click();
}

Comment: see new answer posted by me

Comment: last try :(    i have posted final solution that i can give . sorry for trouble

Answer (score 0):

```
$(upfiles).each(function(index, file) 
                {
                    if(total_size > limit) // size limit comparision
                         display_removebutton = "<img width='20px' style='cursor:pointer;' height='20px' class='class_remove' id='remove_"+int_loop+"' src='images/DeleteRed.png' />"
                    size = Math.round( file.size / 1024 );
                    if(size > 1024) 
                            size_display =  Math.round(size / 1024 * 100)/100 + ' mb';     // converted to mb
                    else
                            size_display = size + ' kb';
                    if(size > limit)
                    {
                        style_limitexceed = "style='background:#FFCCCC;border-radius:17px;height:30px;margin-top:6px;'";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        style_limitexceed = "";
                    }
                    $('#total').append("<div id='div_selec"+int_loop+"' "+style_limitexceed+"><b>File Name :</b> "+file.name + "<b> Size:</b>" + size_display + display_removebutton + "</div>"+"" ); 
                    $("#remove_"+int_loop).click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if(confirm( "Do you want to delete file : "+ file.name+ "?" ) === true)
                    {

// here we need to remove the click event for **fileupload input tag**
                            var curr_id = this.id;
                            var id = curr_id.substr(7);
                            $("#div_selec"+id).empty();
                            upfiles.splice(index, 1)
                            $("#div_selec"+id).fadeOut('slow');
                            total_size = total_size - (file.size/1024);
                            if(total_size < limit)
                            {
                                $("#total img:last-child").remove()
                                $("#div_errorLog").fadeOut('slow');
                            }
                    }
                     });
                     int_loop++;
                });
```